# Generating random variates in Excel

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I am very confused with a question I have found in relation to Excel. I am hoping someone can help me do this or at-least give me direction in which I can figure out how to do this. So far I don't even know where to get started.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this question, from a book or a homework assignment

Comment: @satishramanathan it is from a past homework assignment but I don't have solutions so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Link:  http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC8QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ms.uky.edu%2F~lee%2Famsptech%2FRunningSimulation.doc&ei=JWW2U8q5GIKCOMKCgcgJ&usg=AFQjCNHAzRiW5lICffJIBEDSP-tEQuUB5Q&bvm=bv.70138588,d.ZWU&cad=rja

Comment: @georg how do I use that simulation to do the above question? I only know how to do confidence intervals and few other things so when I saw this question, it is the last question in that assignment so it is the hardest, I couldn't even understand what the question wants me to do..

Comment: I don't understand how to do what this question is asking....

Comment: @user2997307: Unfortunately, I can not much English. Working as help to add ins Excel "Data Analysis."

Comment: @georg https://translate.google.com/

Comment: In what Excel works? (I Excel 7). You have an active Excel add ins "Data Analysis"?

Comment: @georg, Very nice of you to help this lad.  I have chipped in what you have to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Linearity of Expectation

$E(W) = 3\times E(U) - 2\times E(D) + 4\times E(N) \times E(B)$

Mean of Uniform Distribution $= \frac{(a+b)}{2}$, for $E(U) = \frac{(2+4)}{2} = 4$

$E(D) = \frac{(3+7)}{2} = 5$

Mean of a Normal = Mean $= 3.5$

Mean of a Bernoulli = $p = 0.65$

Putting all together $E(W) = 3\times4 - 2\times 5 + 4\times 3.5\times 0.65 = 11.1$

Your simulation of 100 samples of W should average to somewhere close to 11.1

Attached you will see the set up in EXCEL with formulas to get it in the top most row.

Copy those formulas 100 times and draw the graph and compute average as below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for taking the effort to help me to such detail. Really appreciate it. I didn't even know how to start but now I can better understand what this question wants since you did it so clearly

Comment: @user2997307, You are welcome, Good Luck on your assignment.

Comment: what is B in the W= formula column? N is the normal N column, U is the U column but what is the B column?

Comment: B is the Bernoulli column.  It takes on the value of 1 or 0.  The way you generate that is create a random number ( interemediate) from (0,1) using Rand() function. If that number is less than .65 (which is the probability of success), then you assign 1 else you assign 0. Thanks

Comment: What is the graph plotting?

Comment: I got average of 8.738659465. My W column is: 

=3*B87-2*C87+4*F87*D87

Comment: The value of W as a histogram.  That is how the distribution looks.  Just like the normal will look like a bell curve, W looks almost like an exponential.

Comment: You don't use the intermediate column for W=??

Comment: Refresh, the worksheet, most often times it will hover around 11.1. One time may be an exception

Comment: No Create the intermeidate column and use it to get Bernoulli and then multiply Bernoulli column in W not the interemediate column

Comment: You are most welcome. Say thanks to Goerg he was trying to help you